# How to delete all spaces between a specific character and any other character in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have ah HTML string such as this:

```
<p>      some text    </p>     <b>  more    text</b>
```

How can I use regular expressions or some other means to remove all the spaces between the beginning and end of tags, and anything else? In this instance, to get this:

```
<p>some text</p><b>more    text</b>
```

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to process HTML, use a DOM parser.

Comment: The spaces between `</p>     <b>` aren't between the beginning and end tags of anything.

Comment: You should generally leave one space, otherwise words that are in different tags will run together, unless you use CSS to add margins or borders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I use regular expressions ...

You don't use RegExp for such a task, because of:

- [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747)
- [Why it's not possible to use regex to parse HTML/XML: a formal explanation in layman's terms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751105)

Instead, you first parse your HTML and work on the resulting DOM.
You can do this by adding it to `innerHTML` of an element you created and then use [`document.createNodeIterator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createNodeIterator) to iterate over all `Text` nodes.

```js
// create an element that holds your HTML
let cleanupNode = document.createElement("cleanup-root");

// set the innerHTML of that to your input html,
// so that it is parsed and converted into DOM elements
cleanupNode.innerHTML = "<p>      some text    </p>     <b>  more    text</b>";

// Create an iterator that can be used to iterate over all Text nodes
let textIterator = document.createNodeIterator(cleanupNode, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);

let currentNode;
while ((currentNode = textIterator.nextNode())) {
  // trim the contents of the text node and assign it back
  currentNode.data = currentNode.data.trim();
}

// read back the innterHTML
console.log(cleanupNode.innerHTML);
```

If you want to avoid that Text nodes that consist only out of spaces becoming empty you could do:

```js
// create an element that holds your HTML
let cleanupNode = document.createElement("cleanup-root");

// set the innerHTML of that to your input html,
// so that it is parsed and converted into DOM elements
cleanupNode.innerHTML = "<p>      some text    </p>     <b>  more    text</b>";

// Create an iterator that can be used to iterate over all Text nodes
let textIterator = document.createNodeIterator(cleanupNode, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);

let currentNode;
while ((currentNode = textIterator.nextNode())) {
  let newData = currentNode.data.trim();
  if (newData.length == 0) {
     newData = ' ';
  }
  currentNode.data = newData;
}

// read back the innterHTML
console.log(cleanupNode.innerHTML);
```